Let $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic. If $f$ satisfies "$\arg z = \pm \frac{\pi}{3}\implies f(z)$ is real" then $f(\frac{1}{2})$ is real.
Let $f: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic. If $f$ satisfies the condition "whenever $\arg z = \pm \frac{\pi}{3}, f(z)$ is real," prove that $f(\frac{1}{2})$ is real.
Now, the condition "whenever $\arg z \dots$" applies to all $z=re^{\pm i \pi /3}$ for $r>0$. The classic points that come to mind are $e^{i\pi/3} = \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $e^{-i\pi/3} = \frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Any other point satisfying the condition is just a scalar multiple of $e^{\pm i \pi /3}$.
Now, if we want to show that $f(\frac{1}{2})$ is real, it seems awfully likely that we'll be using $e^{\pm i \pi/3}$ in particular. I observe that by hypothesis,
$$f\left(e^{i\pi/3}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{2}+ i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \in \mathbb{R}$$
Given this finding, it seems that I need to show the specific case that $f(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) \in \mathbb{R} \implies f(\frac{1}{2}) \in \mathbb{R}$. I suspect this can be done using the identity theorem but I can't quite think of a function $g$ and a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ for which $f=g$ on $S$. The fact that $f$ is an analytic function on $\mathbb{D}$ in particular seems to hint that there is an elementary result that would be of use here.

$f(e^{i\pi/3})$ is not defined.

I don't think your approach can possibly work. Knowing an analytic function is real at one point is never enough to conclude it's real at some other particular point. You have to somehow use the fact that it's real everywhere on both of those two rays.

@amsmath how is it not defined? $\arg e^{i\pi/3} = \pi /3$; so $f(e^{i \pi /3})$ is real. I'm just using the hypothesis

Is your disk closed or open?

As you write it, the function is defined only on the open unit disk $\mathbb D$. BTW, if the claim is true, then $f$ is also real on $(0,1/2)$. For this, let $s\in (0,1/2)$ and define $g(z) = f(2sz)$. Then $g$ is defined on $\mathbb D$ and $g(te^{\pm i\pi/3}) = f(2ste^{\pm i\pi/3})\in\mathbb R$. Hence, $f(s) = g(1/2)\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, such a function would satisfy $f(s+it) = \overline{f(s-it)}$ for $s\in (0,1/2)$ by the Schwarz reflection principle.

Show that if $g(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ satisfies $g(r)$ real when $0\le r<1$ then $c_n$ is real by noting that inductively the derivatives of any order at $0<r<1$ can be computed on the real line so they are real and then the derivatives of any order at zero are real too by continuity; apply this for $f(ze^{\pm i\pi/3})$ to deduce that if $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ then $a_ne^{\pm in\pi/3}$ is real and from here answer follows immediately as $a_{3n}$ real and the others are zero etc

@Randall ah, oops. It's open. I see now

@Conrad: I think that's an answer.

$\omega :=\exp\big(\frac{i\pi}{3}\big)$and $F(z) := f(z) -\overline{f(\overline z)}$, then $F(0)=0$. If $F\neq 0$ then in $B(0,\delta)$, $F(z) = h(z)^k$ for univalent $h$ and $k\in \mathbb N$; $h$ preserves angles between line segments  $r\cdot \omega \cap B(0,\delta)$ and $r \cdot\overline \omega \cap B(0,\delta)$ which $\cong 2\omega$ however under the image of $F$ their angle  $\cong 3\omega$ and there is no multiplication in $\mathbb Z/(6\mathbb Z)$ that sends $[2]\mapsto [3]$ so $k\notin \mathbb N$ and $F=0$. Unfortunately I'd use an obscure winding number argument to make this rigorous.
